# Complicated Sql Query Of Joining Two Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I having Following Two Tables and wants the result date and bank wise. The Example is as below.

```
Table1: Name:- AccountMast                      
companyID   A/CID   Name          BalDR BalCR   
102         14      SHOBHA        NULL  NULL    
102         15      SONKI         NULL  NULL    
102         16      BANK OF INDIA null  12000       

Table2 Name :- DeBank                       
companyID   transID  date        name          particulars  deposit withdrawal
102         2        12/04/2012  BANK OF INDIA MAHENDRA     1000    NULL
102         4        15/04/2012  CENTRAL BANK  MAHENDRA     1000    NULL
102         3        20/05/2012  BANK OF INDIA MAHENDRA     2000    NULL


Result                      
BANK WISE RESULT BANK OF INDIA              
date        transID particulars deposit withdrawal  BALANCE 
01/04/2012          BAL B/F                         12000   
12/04/2012    2     MAHENDRA    1000    NULL        13000 
20/05/2012    3     MAHENDRA    2000    NULL        15000


BANK WISE RESULT CENTRAL BANK OF INDIA              
date        transID particulars deposit withdrawal  BALANCE**   
01/04/2012          BAL B/F             
15/04/2012   4      MAHENDRA    2000    NULL        2000
```

So what is the sql statement for it?.

Comment: And what is the relationship between `AccountMast` and `DeBank`?

Comment: Presumably, `AccountMast` holds some historical balances for some banks. The key seems to be the `Name` column. `AccountMast` appears to have a 1 to many relationship with `DeBank` on the `name` key. The `DeBank` table appears to hold some aggregated transactions. I surmise that you would like to produce a kind of balance sheet for `name` combining these two tables. If my comments are correct you should update the question accordingly.

Comment: @Jodrell, You are right the AccountMast and Debank is having relationship with keys Name and name and companyID. debank also having aggregate function like to update Balance Columns with + and - deposit and withdrawal columns With Balance. the opbalDR/CR of AccountMast should consider with first columns of debank as a statring date of the year and count as closing balance.